# My laravel app gives 419 on login inside Docker Environment

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I am currently trying to dockerfy my laravel application. I am using the following repo to do it: https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel

The basis behind this repo, is that you should be able to clone it, insert your laravel application into the "src" folder, and the run `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d` and then finish setting up application. After all of these steps are done, you should have a fully functioning application.

This process worked pretty well, however, I am running into a weird issue that I am not running into on my local environment (MAMP). For some reason, when I try to log into my site, I am directed to a page that looks like this:

[image: 419 error]

Now, I am aware, based on my previous research, that this error has to do with CSRF Token Authentification. However, as aforementioned, the site is fully functioning when running it on my MAMP server and I have never had this issue before. All forms, including the login, has the CSRF token set, and upon inspection, I can confirm that its there:

[image]

Note, that I am using the file driver for sessions and I can confirm that the session files are being created and I can find the respective token in the file:

[image]

Additionally, I have cleared all my caches. The application key has been newly generated. And, I have tried simply hard reloading my browser. These are all things I tried during my research, but everything has come up unsuccessful.

Additonally information:

- Server: nginx
- Php: 7.4
- Laravel: 8.4

Comment: Try to change the config variables in your .env file for session. Check the laravel/laravel repository for the example. Then, after that, clear cache etc.

Comment: Try to make the session driver [Rides, Database or shared file]